# How can I combine multiple Regex strings into one?

Tags: regex

My code has five different Regex strings:

```
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[see=[^\]]*\]]");

            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));

            regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[note=[^\]]*\]");

            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));

            regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[restr=[^\]]*\]");

            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));

            regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[ant=[^\]]*\]");

            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));

            regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[syn=[^\]]*\]");

            phraseSources
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));
```

Is there a way that I can combine these into just  one Regex?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of matching text for each regex?

Comment: *"Is there a way that I can combine these into just one Regex?"* -- there are multiple ways to combine two `regex`es into a single one. It depends on what to you want to achieve with the new `regex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use or operator inside inner group

```
(\n  )?\[((see|note|ant|restr|syn)=[^\]]*)\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/CyHvNh/1

Answer (score 0):

Use the | operator and group all with parentesis ()